# Google Postmaster Tools, No Data to Display Message

Tags: google-postmaster

I added my domain to Postmaster Tools and have my domain verified.

Unfortunately when I tried to check the data (it is already 3 days until today), it showed **No data to display at this time. Please come back later** message.

Actually SPF & DKIM are already set up correctly (below is my Check MX result).

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

[image: Check MX result]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, you need to have a minimum level of activity (of the order of several hundred messages) before it will show up. I’m not sure why, but it may be to limit the ability to identify individuals. My own very active accounts still get some of these “no data” days.

Also bear in mind that google postmaster tools is a buggy mess that hardly works at the best of times, for example a spam rating of “bad” will often coincide with a spam reporting rate of zero. It’s also about the only google service that has no support channel whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Synchro for your answer.

Comment: Good to know its a bad tool. My new server is passing mxtoolbox tests bht I had some email straight up not delivered and some in spam. I was trying to assess my domain reputation but my email volume is low (email confirmations). Do you have alternatives to recommend?

Comment: There is no alternative because in order to operate, it needs to be supported internally by Google, and nobody else can do that. There are deliverability measuring services (such as ReturnPath), but they are very expensive.

Comment: @Synchro is there any source for this information?

Comment: Nothing explicit, but google is the only entity in a position to operate such a service, just like nobody but Microsoft can access internal functions of Outlook.com, or that nobody but me can access the spam filter config on my own mail server.